# How to sort ArrayList of extend classes?

Tags: java, class, sorting, arraylist, compiler-errors

Here's a main class `Employee.java` and 2 another classes that extend main class. `ArrayList<Employee>` contains objects from `createFixedEmployee.java` and `createPerHourEmployee`. How to sort objects in `ArrayList` by salary, and if some objects got same salary then sort their names alphabetically?

I tried to use `Comparator.comparing();` but doesn't work, i get an error `Cannot resolve method getMonthSalary();` Here's a code:

**createPerHourEmployee.java**

```
public class createPerHourEmployee extends Employee {
    private double salary;

    public createPerHourEmployee() {}

    public double getSalaryPerHour() { return this.salary; }

    public double setSalaryPerHour(double value) {
        return this.salary = value;
    }


    public createPerHourEmployee (int _id, String _name, double _salary) {
        setEmployeeID(_id);
        setEmployeeName(_name);
        this.salary = _salary;
    }

    public double getMonthSalary() {
        return salary * (20 * 0.8);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getEmployeeID() + ", " + getEmployeeName() + ", " + getSalaryPerHour();
    }
}
```

**createFixedEmployee.java**

```
public class createFixedEmployee extends Employee {
    private double salary;

    public createFixedEmployee() {}

    public double getSalaryFixed() {
        return this.salary;
    }

    public double setSalaryFixed(double value) {
        return this.salary = value;
    }

    public createFixedEmployee(int _id, String _name, double _salary) {
        setEmployeeID(_id);
        setEmployeeName(_name);
        this.salary = _salary;
    }

    public double getMonthSalary() {
        return this.salary;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getEmployeeID() + ", " + getEmployeeName() + ", " + getSalaryFixed();
    }

}
```

Employee.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public abstract class Employee {
    private int base_id;
    private String base_name;

    public int getEmployeeID () {
        return this.base_id;
    }

    public int setEmployeeID (int value) {
        return this.base_id = value;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName () {
        return this.base_name;
    }

    public String setEmployeeName(String value) {
        return this.base_name = value;
    }

    public abstract double getMonthSalary();

    public static void main(String[] argc) {
        ArrayList<Employee> Employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Employee.add(new createPerHourEmployee(1, "asd", 1300));
        Employee.add(new createFixedEmployee(7, "asds", 14025));
        Employee.add(new createPerHourEmployee(2, "nikan", 1230));
        Employee.add(new createPerHourEmployee(3, "nikalo", 12330));
        Employee.add(new createFixedEmployee(6, "aaaa", 14025));
        Employee.add(new createFixedEmployee(4, "nikaq", 140210));
        Employee.add(new createFixedEmployee(5, "nikas", 124000));
        Employee.add(new createFixedEmployee(6, "nikab", 14025));


        Employee.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getMonthSalary)
              .thenComparing(Employee::getEmployeeName)); // here is an error

    }
}
```

So I have tried to use

```
Employee.sort(Comparator.comparing(createFixedEmployee::getMonthSalary).
                thenComparing(createFixedEmployee::getEmployeeName));
```

It works fine, but I need to sort for all classes, not only one class.

Comment: @Mureinik: I realized that and posted an answer at the same time you did. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Mureinik Oh sure. I couldn't find out this issue.. I'll make a note of that, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sorting a `List<T>`, you can definitely use functional references to any of `T`'s ancestors methods. The issue here is with the name you give to the list - You've named the local variable `Employee`, which hides the name of the type `Employee` when you try to create the function references in the `Comparator`. Just give it a better name, and you should be fine. E.g.:

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
// Or better yet: List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

employeeList.add(new createPerHourEmployee(1, "asd", 1300));
employeeList.add(new createFixedEmployee(7, "asds", 14025));
employeeList.add(new createPerHourEmployee(2, "nikan", 1230));
employeeList.add(new createPerHourEmployee(3, "nikalo", 12330));
employeeList.add(new createFixedEmployee(6, "aaaa", 14025));
employeeList.add(new createFixedEmployee(4, "nikaq", 140210));
employeeList.add(new createFixedEmployee(5, "nikas", 124000));
Employee.add(new createFixedEmployee(6, "nikab", 14025));


employeeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getMonthSalary)
      .thenComparing(Employee::getEmployeeName));
```

Comment: Can I trouble you for answering my mini-question? How to sort by `Comparator.comparing();` in descending order?

Comment: You could use `Comparator.comparing(...).reversed()`.

Answer (score 1):

In `main`, you've given your local variable the name `Employee`. That shadows the identifier of your `Employee` class. Variable names shouldn't start with a capital letter anyway, *should* be in the plural when referring to an array or list (unless they end with "list" or similar), and ideally shouldn't be the same as any of your class names.

So change the variable to `employees`. Fix that, and the version using `Employee::getMonthSalary` and such works:

```
employees.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getMonthSalary)
      .thenComparing(Employee::getEmployeeName));
```

---

I would also change `createPerHourEmployee` to `PerHourEmployee` because the overwhelming convention in Java is for class names to start with a capital letter and be nouns, not verbs. Similarly, `createFixedEmployee` would be (say) `SalariedEmployee`.